# Como puedo acceder a este elemento de un Object Symfony

Tags: php, array, symfony, object

como puedo acceder a este una parte del elemento Object, a traves de Symfony?

Estoy consultanto una api externa que me devuelve un object.

He hecho un var_dump del object y esta es la estructura:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)[951]
  public 'headers' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag)[954]
      protected 'computedCacheControl' => 
        array (size=2)
          'no-cache' => boolean true
          'private' => boolean true
      protected 'cookies' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'headerNames' => 
        array (size=2)
          'cache-control' => string 'Cache-Control' (length=13)
          'date' => string 'Date' (length=4)
      protected 'headers' => 
        array (size=2)
          'cache-control' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'date' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      protected 'cacheControl' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  protected 'content' => string 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/documentos/0-2020-05-27_17-18-45.pdf' (length=82)
  protected 'version' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  protected 'statusCode' => int 200
  protected 'statusText' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  protected 'charset' => null
```

yo necesito acceder al elemento 'content' para enviar ese enlace al usuario.

el log de symfony me devuelve esto

```
[2020-05-27 21:26:50] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response as array" at D:\Desarrollo\backend\src\AppBundle\Controller\InfoController.php line 794 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Cannot use object of type Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response as array at D:\\Desarrollo\\backend\\src\\AppBundle\\Controller\\InfoController.php:794)"} []
```

en la linea 794 tengo esta linea de codigo:

```
$justificante = $urlJustificante['content']
```

De antemano Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de un objeto de tipo response, de symfony httpFoundation. No es un tipo object como tal.

El error te indica que intentas acceder como si fuera un array.

```
$justificante = $urlJustificante['content']
```

Es incorrecto, pues es la forma de acceder a un array.

Para acceder al contenido, tampoco puedes usar:

```
$justificante = $urlJustificante->content
```

Debido a que es protected. Sin embargo el objeto response tiene un método específico para ello:

```
$justificante = $urlJustificante->getContent()
```

**nota** asegúrate de revisar el status de respuesta con el método getStatusCode()

Comment: Gracias @jakala, funciona correctamente